# Why a person when jumps out of boat applies a force at the corner of boat?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

I marked the red region why the person pushes the boat at that point?

What I think is they push the boat at that point to avoid friction between his leg and boat surface. If I am wrong then please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true not only for the boat, but when jumping from a hard surface (e.g., over a trench) or when descending steps:

- this way the distance of a jump is shorter
- one pushes not only in vertical, but also in the horizontal direction, thus giving oneself higher horizontal momentum, which permits jumping further
- in case of descending stairs, this also permits to spend less energy, since one is essentially falling (using gravity to accelerate)
- avoiding slipping, as suggested in the OP, may be an additional reason - this may be valid on a wet boat or, e.g., when moving on an iced lake/skating ring (where one may want to push against a crack in the ice.)

Here is an interesting study involving stairs: [*Stair Gait in Older Adults Worsens With Smaller Step Treads and When Transitioning Between Level and Stair Walking*](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fspor.2020.00063/full). One of the conclusions is that *foot overhang* (i.e., how much of the foot is beyond the corner) is higher in younger and physically fit adults, who are moving faster and feel less secure, whereas older people tend to keep their foot firmly on the flat surface.
[image]